# Binary numbers to list

Tags: python, list

I have written the following program in Python:

```
s = []
for e in random_key:
    s = str(e)
    print(s)
```

where the list random_key is

```
random_key = ['0011111011100101', '0000010111111011', '0011100110110100', 
              '1000010101010010', '0011001011001111', '1101101101110011', 
              '1100001111111011', '0000100000110100', '0101111010100101', 
              '1001100101100001']
```

The output of the program is

```
1111011010110011 
1011000110011100 
0011011001100010 
0000011100100001 
1111111010000100 
0110110101100011 
1011100011000101 
1011101011100010 
1101101101001010 
1000011110110000
```

which is not correct. How can I fix the code?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I can't reproduce the output that you posted. Why do you think you get that output?

Comment: If ```random_key``` contains strings, why to convert them to strings again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am able to read your thoughts (not sure about that ..). Would you like them to 10 based numbers?

```
random_key = ['0011111011100101', '0000010111111011', '0011100110110100',
              '1000010101010010', '0011001011001111', '1101101101110011',
              '1100001111111011', '0000100000110100', '0101111010100101',
              '1001100101100001']

numbers = [int(x, 2) for x in random_key]
print(numbers)
```

output

```
[16101, 1531, 14772, 34130, 13007, 56179, 50171, 2100, 24229, 39265]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
s = list()
for e in random_key:
    s.append(str(e))

print(s)
```

Returns:

```
['0011111011100101', '0000010111111011', '0011100110110100', '1000010101010010', '0011001011001111', '1101101101110011', '1100001111111011', '0000100000110100', '0101111010100101', '1001100101100001']
```